# .NET convert external CSS to inline CSS

Tags: .net, css

I'm looking for a tool that converts external CSS to inline CSS. The resulting HTML is used in e-mail and for PDF creation.

Comment: Does it have to be .NET? Is an external tool out of the question?

Comment: Check out some of the existing questions about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code

Comment: It should be in .NET so I can call the dll in my c# code.

Comment: Problem solved by using HtmlAgilityPackl & Fizzler I've uploaded a zip file with an example and the required DLL's [HtmlCssMergeExample.rar](http://www.elime.be/downloads/HtmlCssMergeExample.rar). The file example.txt contains an example on how to call my code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Premailer.Net should do the trick it's written in C#

> C# .Net library, that moves your stylesheets to inline style
>   attributes, for maximum compatibility with E-mail clients.

Here is the Git repo:
https://github.com/milkshakesoftware/PreMailer.Net:

Comment: Premailer is indeed the way to go these days.

Answer (score 0):

Using .NET Core, I solved this problem by defining a function as follows

```
public static string InlineFile(string path)
{
    return System.IO.File.ReadAllText("wwwroot/" + path);
}
```

and then calling it in a view as

```
<style>
    @Html.Raw(Utilities.InlineFile("account/css/style.css"));
</style>
```

The reason behind separately defining the function is to avoid changing all paths in case the hosting environment changes. Beware that you cannot inline media rules.

Comment: That does put your CSS in the same file as your HTML but does not inline it. Inline CSS resiedes in your HTML elements in the style attribute.